# CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber not support 0 at beginning

Tags: ios

CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber not support 0 at beginning

eg.

[image: error]

Add 0 in front of the number becomes 8-binary number,
But my phone number has 0 in front of it.

If my phone number is 010-12345678,
8612345678 is not matched,
8601012345678 is not matched,
01012345678 is not matched.

Comment: Have you tried omitting the leading 0?

Comment: Can not be omitting,because my phone number is 010-xxxxxxxx,the area code of my country is 86.

Comment: 0 is the national access digit and is typically omitted when specifying numbers.  It is odd that Apple has specified `CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber` as an INT64.  I would have expected them to use an e.164 string.  Since they have used an integer, a leading 0 cannot be specified, since there are 0s in front of almost any integer.  I assume, then, that Apple simply matches numbers right to left, so `12345678` would match `86012345678` unless there was a more specific match

Comment: you are right.Apple only supports int64 here, do not support the string, I also hope that Apple can support the string, this will be a lot easier.

Comment: Have you tried just specifying 1012345678?

Comment: I have tried this format,not match.

Comment: OK.  I set up a test callkit extension and the format that you have to use is e.164 without the leading + (Since it is an integer not a string).  To call my number in country you dial 02 63xx xxxx, but internationally you would dial 61 2 63xx xxxx, so I added 61263xxxxxx to the extension and it displayed the caller identity correctly, so in your case I would expect that you would add 861012345678

Answer (score 2):

Some tips for someone who might still struggle on this... In short, if you number is 010-12345678, then 8612345678 should be the choice. Formats like "+8612345678" as a string worked for me too.

Just ran into the similar issue, and found out the reason why Call Directory extension sometimes "does not work" is simply not because of your phone number format. iOS will actually cache your phone numbers which are set when the extension is ran previously, i.e. it will not update your blocking or the identification phone numbers each time you change your source code and restart you app extension as you expected.

One way to invalidate the iOS cache is to toggle your app's option in Settings -> Phone -> Call Blocking & Identification (and maybe restart your app as well).